# Compare nested foreach variables in php without globals?

Tags: php, foreach, compare

I have multiple foreach's parsing data that I need to compare with each other. For instance:

```
foreach ($xml_string->xpath('//location') as $character) {

  $xml_name = $character->earthname;

  $compare_remote = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/", "", $xml_name));

}

foreach ( $whatever as $key => $value ) {

 foreach ($value as $pkey){

   $value_name = $pkey["spacename"];

   $compare_local = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', $value_name));

 }
}
```

How can I loop through both sets of foreach to compare all the values in `$compare_remote` with the values in `$compare_local` , I will probably be using `levenshtein()`, but for the sake of this example anything will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach ($xml_string->xpath('//location') as $character) {

      $xml_name = $character->earthname;

      $compare_remote = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/", "", $xml_name));

       foreach ( $whatever as $key => $value ) {

          foreach ($value as $pkey){

              $value_name = $pkey["spacename"];

              $compare_local = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', $value_name));

                if( $compare_remote==$compare_local) echo "match";
          }
        }

 }
```

Comment: No this can result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Wyck how come? what is your `$whatever` variable? This is looping through your `$string->path` query and then compares with the values in `$wahtever` array you are having there.

Comment: The $whatever variable is actually a global array, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Whyck Dot' get me wrong but that doesn't explain why would be stuck in infinite loop?? If `$whatever` variable is global and has soem array values and if doesn't references values from  `  foreach ($xml_string->xpath('//location') as $character)` than the possibility of infinite loop is same as in your example. Furthermore you're not assignign anything. So again, the possibility is the same. But anyway, if you are not willing to try the solution...

Comment: Yes I was wrong, sorry I had some extra code in there I did not see, your solution does work.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what it is your comparing, you could use an associative array outside both loops as key / value lookups. If there is a common key then you can operate on the same values that were evaluated by both loops. Ideally I know you want to iterate over both at the same time, but this is a possibility that results in one evaluated set of data. Unique keys are preserved.

```
$compare[];

foreach ($xml_string->xpath('//location') as $character) {

  $xml_name = $character->earthname;

  $compare[strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/", "", $xml_name))];

}

foreach ( $whatever as $key => $value ) {

 foreach ($value as $pkey){

   $value_name = $pkey["spacename"];

   $compare[strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", '', $value_name))];

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is what I am looking for, I'm still not 100% sure how to implement it though, if you happen to know of any documentation I would appreciate it.

Comment: You can use the same value for Key and value. So compare[$name]=$name; Ideally you check if there is a common key isset(compare[$name]) and then do something useful. Maybe give us a an example of what it is your comparing and maybe we can help. When I think of compare I literally think there is a test somewhere like if ($name == $othername), but you don't give us that much information.

Comment: I'm comparing just text strings, but I do not know the values, stuff like " all in one", "fruit salad", "toronto", just regular words.The first loop is an an XML file and the second is an array of words , I just need to find matched, but they are not all spelled correctly, for instance "fruit basket" "Fruit-basket".